# HDMI to USB-C adaptor does not works on ubuntu

Tags: drivers, 20.04, usb, video, hdmi

I bought the adaptor CHOETECH HUB-H12 and it does not display video when connecting the HDMI cable, i have also tested with other adapters (dell) and it does not work.

System info:

```
System:    Kernel: 5.17.3-051703-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: Gnome 3.36.9 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 80YH v: Lenovo ideapad 320-15IKB serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: LENOVO model: Cairo 5A v: SDK0J40688 WIN serial: <filter> UEFI [Legacy]: LENOVO v: 4WCN26WW date: 05/26/2017 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i7-7500U bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Amber Lake rev: 9 L2 cache: 4096 KiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 bogomips: 23199 
           Speed: 800 MHz min/max: 400/3500 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1187 2: 1200 3: 1187 4: 1200 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 620 vendor: Lenovo driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 940MX] vendor: Lenovo driver: nouveau v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: modesetting,nouveau,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,vesa tty: N/A 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.6 direct render: Yes 

Info:      Processes: 251 Uptime: 23m Memory: 11.48 GiB used: 2.61 GiB (22.7%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.4.0 
           Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 inxi: 3.0.38
```

lsusb output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 174f:116a Syntek EasyCamera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e500 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c539 Logitech, Inc. USB Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Hello.  No current version of Ubuntu is running a 5.17 kernel by default.

Comment: @David I changed the default version in attempt to solve the problem but it didn't work.

Comment: What is the output of `lsusb`?

Comment: @vidarlo I've added the output in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your laptop does not support [DP Alt mode](https://www.benq.com/en-us/knowledge-center/knowledge/usb-c-introduction-what-is-dp-alt-mode.html) [according to the manual](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/ideapad320-15isk_320x-15isk_320-15ikb_320x-15ikb_320-15ikbtouch_ug_en_201704.pdf):
[image: Type C port description]

DP Alt mode is required to use the adapter style you have found, and more recent hardware typically supports it. You can confirm what output devices you have by running `xrandr`. It will output a list of ports, and USB-C DP Alt Mode will show up as Displayport:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 276mm x 156mm
[modes truncated as not relevant]
HDMI-A-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Your device will probably show an internal port and a HDMI port. In the output above, from my laptop (Thinkpad A285), there's one HDMI port and two USB-C DP Alt mode ports.

`lsusb` confirms that what you have is an adapter cable, and not a USB device, as it doesn't show up in `lsusb`.

So in short: your laptop can't do video over USB-C. Sorry. There's adapters out there with [DisplayLink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayLink) chips, that acts as a graphic cards over USB. These can be connected to USB3.1 and provide display output, but are typically far more expensive than the simple USB-C alt mode cables, and require DisplayLink driver software installed on the computer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer.

Comment: NP. This can be a tad bit tricky unless you're aware of DP Alt mode. First time I encountered a USB-C display I spent 8 hours of the working day not managing to make it work. Not fun.

Comment: Exacly, i've bought two adapters thinking that may be the problem :( not counting the hours of work i've spent on it.