# USB-C to HDMI adaptor does not work for my second external monitor on Ubuntu 20.04 (Razer Blade Laptop)

Tags: drivers, 20.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi, usb-c

I spent the whole day trying to make my second external monitor work for my laptop (*Razer Blade 14 - Full HD 144Hz - GeForce RTX 3060 - Black* - [Link](https://www.razer.com/gaming-laptops/Razer-Blade-14/RZ09-0427EE23-R3U1)). My primary monitor is connected via HDMI (and worked out of the box from the beginning) and I've been trying to connect the second [monitor](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B08YGFKS35?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details) via a Type-C to HDMI cable ([link](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B06XDMKQKJ?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details) for the cable). The thing is that this configuration works for the same laptop when I use Windows (forgot to mention that I have dual boot in this laptop, Windows 11 & Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with a 5.13.0-52-generic kernel). Does anyone have any idea on how I can fix this?

Here I provide some outputs that I thought they could be useful based on a similar [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402503/hdmi-to-usb-c-adaptor-does-not-works-on-ubuntu).

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4480 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected primary 2560x1440+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 697mm x 392mm
   2560x1440    143.93*+ 120.00    59.95  
   3840x2160     59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98  
   1920x1080    119.88    60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1280x720      59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
DP-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1920x1080    143.98*+  59.99  
DVI-I-4-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-3-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

```
$ lsusb
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 004: ID 25a4:9311 USB C   USB C Video Adaptor      
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 13d3:5279 IMC Networks Integrated RGB Camera
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 045b:0210 Hitachi, Ltd 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 7392:c611 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 046d:c545 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 046d:c332 Logitech, Inc. G502 Proteus Spectrum Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 045b:0209 Hitachi, Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1532:028c Razer USA, Ltd Razer Blade
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04ca:3a24 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

If you need more info please let me know. Thanks in advance for your time!!!

Comment: Could you post some info about your NVidia drivers? Whether you're using proprietary and what version they are etc.

Comment: I'm using the proprietary NVidia drivers (the version is 470). Shall I run any command on the terminal that could provide more useful info?

Comment: That's quite an old version, probably worth updating those first, the latest is 530. You can install them using `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-530`

Comment: I tried it out but still doesn't work :/

Comment: Kernel 5.13 is not a supported kernel in any version of Ubuntu. How and why are you using this kernel?

Comment: Hi @David! Tbh, I have no idea why I'm using this kernel :|
Do you have any (stable/"trustworthy") kernel to suggest? Additionally, if I change (either upgrade or downgrade) my kernel could this result in loss of my personal data?

Comment: The kernel does not in any way affect the files on the hard drive. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes#:~:text=free%20software%20community.-,Linux%20Kernel,kernel%20series%20by%20default%20here.

Comment: Something really strange happened. Apart from 5.13, I also installed Ubuntu `5.15.0-71.78~20.04.1-generic 5.15.92` (which is also supported as I saw [here](https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch/docs/livepatch/reference/kernels)) and each time I was trying to log in I was getting some strange errors.

Now I managed to log in (don't know how) with this new kernel. I have already realized that this solved an issue with my internal WiFi adapter. Looking forward to returning home and testing my two monitors. I'll get back to update the post when I have some news. Thanks a lot!!!